# Posting to wall with Android facebook sdk 4.5.x

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

According [to this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android#permissions) documentation adding a publish permission to my android application, it uses `Session` class which is deprecated now. Can anyone tell me what is the updated way to achieve this? I want to post something on the user's wall with my app. And I found [this is the way](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#publishing) to post something on user's wall, to simply make a POST call on this url:

```
graph.facebook.com
  /{user-id}/feed?
    message={message}&
    access_token={access-token}
```

Is this the correct way or is this somehow deprecated too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the word "Session" occur on the page you are referring to.

Regardless, you can read the ["Sharing on Android"](https://developers.prod.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) docs page to learn how you can publish content from Android devices.

The recommended way of doing this is by using the share dialog, because that does not require users to grant any publishing permissions. Since you have to include the SDK anyway in order to implement Facebook login, you might as well make use of this feature.

Comment: Not in the text , but the sample code snippet they have shown, they use Session class and UiLifecycleHelper class. 
Anyways , will try with sharing too. Thanks.